# Is the "of" in "a lot of" a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

Is "of" in "a lot of time" a preposition?

I am working on a task about the identification of prepositions and their objects. I am not sure about "a lot of", and for some reason it seems unbreakable.

Comment: Originally 'a lot of' simply meant 'a share of'. Nowadays it means 'a large amount of'.  As far as I know 'of' is always a preposition.

Comment: @chasly from UK: I can't think of any counterexamples off the top of my head, so you could be quite right. But the idea that a word (especially a word that can be used as a preposition) can *only* be a single part of speech (ever) is grating. Food for thought for me, to be sure!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Certainly "lots" has come to mean a large amount.

Comment: You produced 3 lots of 14 screws in 30 minutes.

Comment: Probably better to analyse _a lot of_ as a compound quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

Well its followed by a noun,  like a sack of potatoes a sack of is like a determiner 
In the old days a lot was a given quantity that has morphed into use as many I guess,
I picked up a sack of potatoes by which we mean a sack containing potatoes but it could have been a sack of corn so the sack is the  noun and of potatoes describes the contents 
Answer is of a preposition in this case Yes but it acts like a detreminer as we have lost the meaning of lot
Well thats what i reckon but i am not sure but that will work for all of the a lot of`s

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a simple sentence:

> I have a lot of time.

There are two options:

- Either (a lot of) is unbreakable, which would presumably make it a multi-word preposition, or
- It divides into (a lot) [noun phrase] and (of time) [prepositional phrase].

The direct object of the transitive verb *have* is either "lot" or "time." If I say, "I have (a lot of) (time)," then *time* is the direct object, and (a lot of) is....an adjective? Certainly not an unbreakable preposition.

By contrast, If I say, "I have (a lot) (of time)," then the direct object is "lot," and "of time" modifies *lot* by describing what kind of lot it is. So (of time) becomes an adjectival prepositional phrase. That makes more sense.

Thus, "of" in this sentence is a preposition, and "time" is its object.

As an aside, I tried searching for lists of multi-word prepositions that include "a lot of" but came up empty. If anyone else can find something, I'm all ears.

Comment: So, is there any functional reason to ever regard it as a multi-word preposition?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Not that I can think of. But I wanted to leave the door open for people smarter than I am to identify something that I had missed. :-)

Comment: Hmmm, that's not quite correct. If it's one lexical item then it would be a multi-word determiner not a preposition. You van find many instances of multi-word determiners, if you look for them *a few, a little* and so forth ... :)

Comment: Great point, @Araucaria. So the question becomes, is "a lot of" a multi-word determiner, or a noun phrase followed by a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Breaking the structure into "a lot" as a noun phrase and "of time" as a prepositional phrase sounds very plausible, especially if I consider the nominal properties of the word "lot", namely, the 's' that it gets when pluralized and the modifiers it takes like any other noun in a noun pharse (a whole lot, 20 lots...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *of* is a preposition, wherever it appears. It can't be anything else.

However, it appears in ***a lot of*** idioms. As such, it has essentially no meaning; *of* -- or a ghost of *of*, like the *-a* in *kinda* -- appears very frequently in English, and is frequently optional. That is, a speaker uses it when they feel the need for an extra syllable. One can say *three of the small ones* or *three small ones*, for instance.

The phrase  *a lot of* is (as explained in the other answers) a partitive or measure phrase like *three gallons of*, where the first noun phrase refers to some quantitative aspect of the second noun phrase following *of*, but *lot* is not really a compositional constituent any more, except in auction contexts.

Nowadays, *(a)lotta* basically means "much" or "many" -- and in fact it means both of them, so you can use it with plural count nouns **or** with singular mass nouns without worrying about which is which:

- *a lot of money ~ much money*
- *a lot of bricks ~ many bricks*

Answer (score 0):

Of course, "of" and "to" are prepositions. But as these two prepositions have become case markers for genitive and dative in English they are special preposions. I think to do them justice you have to invent a name. I don't need one, because I have no problem with genitive and dative. But perhaps you try case-marker prepositions.

Added:

"A lot of something" has the same structucture as "a bucket of water" or "a sack of flour", an expression indicating how much of what. "Of" is the genitive preposition indicating a partitive genitive.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to diagram this, I found that "I had a lot of time." I subject, had verb, in all actuality the thing I had was "a lot",  determiner followed by head noun, and the "of time" then is the postmodifier for the noun phrase. Yet, we are really using the phrase "a lot" to describe how much-the function of a determiner. That would make the "of time" then the prepositional phrase acting as a noun. I would be on board with either response seeing as how form and function are always playing against each other and in this case it is a draw. From phone sorry about the grammar issues in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Cambridge English Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers), you should take "a lot of" as a whole, which acts as a quantifier.

a [quantifier](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/quantifier) is

> a word or phrase that is used before a noun to show the amount of it that is being considered